# Recyclerview and realm. Should I use a background thread for realm?

Tags: multithreading

I am using a recyclerview in which I show data using realm database.. I am asking myself, shall I use a background thread for realm? I mean I am using a recyclerview and as far asaI I know realm is powerful and fast..should I use a background thread anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd **recommend** using a background thread just to prevent blocking of the UI thread.

Despite how powerful and fast Realm is, and trust me I personally know how good a library it is, it is generally good practice to extract the database data in a background thread.

One approach I would personally take is using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). First subscribe to a custom observable that pulls the data and then simply populate the recycler view after it's completed.